# MySQL - Date-time multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I created an SQL script whose output is only 2 columns:

1. Date-Time
2. Transactions Count (See image 1).

I want this output (See image 2).

Here is the initial SQL script I created below:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(Table1.<DateColumn>, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' | ', SUBSTRING(Table1.<TimeColumn>, 1, 2)) AS 'Date-Time',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Transactions Count'
FROM B2C_BUY_HIST AS Table2
INNER JOIN B2C_BUY_LOG AS Table1 ON Table2.<ID> = Table1.<ID>
WHERE Table1.<ID> = buyhist.<ID>
    AND Table1.<StatusColumn> = 'SUCCESS'
    AND Table1.<DateColumn> BETWEEN '20211001' AND '20211022'
GROUP BY 1;
```

**Image1: This is the output of my initial SQL script**

[image: Image 1 - This is the output of my initial SQL script]

**Image 2- This is the output that what I want**

[image: Image 2- This is the output that what I want]

Comment: Please provide a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) with some sample data and your desired result!

Comment: MySQL doen't provide pivot queries.  MariaDB has pivot tables using the connect engine, but the columns are fixed when you create the table.  PostgreSQL and Oracle allow pivoting, the former using the crosstab table function.  With MySQL you'll need to do some 3GL programming .

Comment: Follow the [pivot] tag.  Also stackoverflow.com has lots of examples.